# PHP PDO result from query

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I am trying to do a query in PHP PDO where it will grab a simple result. So like in my query I need it to find the row where the column group is 'Admin' and show what ever is in the group column. I know that we already know what it should be [Should be admin] but just need to get the query to work. Its only grabbing 1 row from my table, so will I need forsearch?

If I change WHERE group = 'Admin' to WHERE id = '1' it works fine. But I need it so it can be where group = 'admin'

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM groups WHERE group = 'Admin'";
$stm2 = $dbh->prepare($sql2);
$stm2->execute();
$users2 = $stm2->fetchAll();

foreach ($users2 as $row2) {
    print ' '. $row2["group"] .' ';
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What does the database look like?

Comment: @Bonzo http://prntscr.com/2sbr51 & for the structure http://prntscr.com/2sbr83

Answer (score 1):

group is a reserved word in MySQL, that's why it's not working. In general it's a bad idea to use reserved words for your column and table names.
Try using backticks around group in your query to get around this, so:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM groups WHERE `group` = 'Admin'";
```

Also you should really use placeholders for values, because you're already using prepared statement it's a small change.

Edit: just to clarify my last remark about the placeholders. I mean something like this:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM groups WHERE `group` = ?";
$stm2->execute(array('Admin'));
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use [wildcard](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp) in your WHERE Clause:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM groups WHERE group LIKE '%Admin%'";
```

Since the value in your table is not really `Admin` but `Administrator` then using `LIKE` and `wildcard` would search the records which contains admin.